# Holomorphic function and nth derivative.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, connectedness

Let $K$ be a open connected subset of complex numbers and $f$ holomorphic on $K$. If $f=0$ on some open disc $D$ in $K$, then is it true that

1. $n$th derivative of $f$ is $0$ for all points in $D$
2. And this implies $f=0$ on the whole of $K$.

#### Progress

I know that holomorphic implies power series expansion exists about the point and was trying to see if it can be done using just this. My main question is, if $ f$ is holomorphic and zero in some disc then is it zero on any connected set containing that disc?

Comment: Please add some context or thoughts of your own. For example: do you know the identity theorem for holomorphic functions?

Comment: well i know that holomorphic implies power series expansion exists about the point and was trying to see if it can be done using just this.

Comment: My main question is, If f is holomorpic and zero in some disc then is it zero on any connected set containing that disc.

Comment: That is basically the identity principle. One way to proceed is to prove that the set where $f=0$ is both open and closed.

Comment: Can you show me please how you show that the set where f=0 is both open and closed

Comment: and does the identity principle not require you to have an accumulation point?

Comment: You have equality on an open disc! (This has lots of accumulations points.) To show that the zero set is closed, just use that $f$ is continuous. For openness, use the power series representation.

Comment: so sorry about this but is it possible to show me how you would show that the zero set is closed

Comment: Let $Z=\{w \in K \, | \, f(w)=0\}$ and let $\{z_n\}$ be a sequence of points in $Z$ converging to some $z \in K$.  We need to show that $z \in Z$, i.e., that $f(z)=0$.  But this is immediate by continuity: $f(z)=f(\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty} f(z_n)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

By the [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) both claims follow trivially.